# Can we pass whole data in webview

Tags: android, xml-parsing, android-webview

I am new in android development.i have to parse data from xml.my xml url is-
http://mobileecommerce.site247365.com/admin/catdata.xml

i am able to success parse cat_desc data.Can i show whole data in webview or webview can display only url?

Comment: look at my answer. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this, it is the correct answer, as sometimes it is possible it wont show the web view due to some special chas like % and # etc... so use this :-

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("<some URL>", stringData,"text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can display data in a `WebView` using

```
webview.loadData(yourString, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Comment: Hi Sherif thanks for reply if my string contain urls,imagesurl,texts so is it work?

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods for display string data in WebView,

either

```
webview.loadData( stringData, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

or

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("<some URL>", stringData,"text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Comment: In your case I think you have to try, webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://mobileecommerce.site247365.com", stringData,"text/html", "utf-8", null);