# How to pass html tag in webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have to pass whole html tag in webview.

My url is- `http://mobileecommerce.site247365.com/admin/catdata.xml`

I parse cat_desc , please check url for first `cat_desc`

```
    public class WebviewActivity extends Activity 
    {

        WebView mWebView;
    String s="first cat_desc from url";

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        showPdf();
    }
    private void showPdf() 
    {
        WebView webview = new WebView(this); 
        setContentView(webview); 
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
        webview.loadData(s, "text/html", "utf-8");
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't call 'setContentView(R.layout.main)' if you call 'setContentView' anyway for the web view - R.layout.main won't even show, you are just wasting RAM and CPU for the inflated layout.

Comment: ok i remove this line.please tell me what should i do for my question?

Comment: I've never used WebView, and I didn't understand exactly what did you mean in your question, sorry :(

Comment: What do you mean by 'pass whole html tag' ? Do you want to load that url in your webview?

Comment: hi jong.please check above url.and check first cat_desc tag data, i want to pass whole cat_desc data in web_view.IS it possible?

Comment: Could you please explain what problem you are facing? Are you having trouble getting the cat_desc tag? Or loading it?

Comment: my problem is i am not able to load data in webview.how can i do this? Is it possible to load whole html tag in webview?

Comment: Why you have accepted this answer unless you received the desirable solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832106/can-we-pass-whole-data-in-webview, you should have updated this question instead.

Comment: hi paresh i pass text it's working.Is it possible to pass html tags in webview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about xml parsers. Then you can check how to set the HTML code in the cat_desc tag into your webview.

You can read about xml parsing in android [here](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-%E2%80%93-using-domparser).

Another option is, you can try to substring out the cat_desc tag content using regular string methods (substring, indexOf). Use the method you are comfort with.